# When I store the function in a variable, it prints out a slightly different result? ("undefined" thrown in at the end)

Tags: javascript, function, variables, undefined

I'm self-studying JavaScript and new to functions. I'm playing around with it and the results of one I made confuse me a bit--please see my code below. The first time my function is run, it spells out "cat" as "c", "a", "t" in the console. That makes sense to me. But when I store it in a variable and call that variable, it does the same exact thing but with "undefined" at the end. Shouldn't the results be the same? I don't understand how there is "undefined" when you call a function via a variable. I'd really appreciate any help to explain this.

```js
function printCat(x) {
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    console.log(x[i])
  }
}

printCat("cat")

var func1 = printCat

console.log(func1("cat"))
```

Comment: The `undefined` is just the return type of your function. You ignore that in the first call and in the second one you explicitly print it using `console.log`. Replace the last line with just `func1("cat")` (or add the `console.log` to the `printCat` line) and you'll see that there's not difference.

Comment: "*Shouldn't the results be the same?*" you're not calling them the same way. The equivalent to `printCat("cat")` is `func1("cat")`, not `console.log (func1("cat"))`

Answer (score 1):

The output is the same. It prints cat.
undefined is being printed by the last `console.log()`.
When you print `console.log('A')`, it prints 'A'.
As you are trying to `console.log(function)`, it prints undefined.